# Can you run a multiple regression where variables use different Likert scales?

Tags: multiple-regression, likert

I have 8 predictor variables and 1 criterion variable, all variables are measured by 9 different constructs, some are 0-4 Likert scales, some  are 1-5 Likert scales, can I use their mean scores and run a multiple regression?

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, @Shirley? Do you mean that you have 9 different Likert *items*, where some are numbered 0-4 & others 0-5? Or do you have multiple items (forming a *scale*) per construct, and you want to average over all the the items w/i a construct to get a single mean for each variable? Or something else? In formulating your question, it might help to read this blog post: [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/). Also, if your criterion is ordinal, you might consider ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response and advice. Here is the situation:

Comment: I have 8 predictor variables using 8 different questionnaires. These 8 variables are stress level, self esteem, peer relationship, family relationship, neuroticism, boredom proneness, depression, social anxiety (So there are 8 different questionnaires). However, this 8 questionnaires have its each form of scales.

Comment: For example, Stress questionnaire is using 0-4 scale (0 = strongly disagree, 4 = strong agree); Self esteem is using 0-3 scale (0 = strongly disagree, 3 = strong agree); Peer relationship is using 1-4 scale (1 = strongly disagree, 4 = strong agree) and etc. My criterion variable is Online gaming addiction using 1-4 scale (1 = strongly disagree, 4 = strong agree)

Comment: So what I'm doing now is that I calculate mean score for these 8 predictor and 1 criterion variable (in other word, I have one single mean for each variable, so in total I have 8 predictor mean scores and 1 criterion mean score now).

Comment: My question is, since the questionnaires are using different form of likert scale, I wonder if this is alright to use these 8 predictor mean scores and 1 criterion mean score to run multiple regression, in order to get the prediction relationship.

Comment: Please do advise! Appreciate your help!

Comment: More information for you, I'm planning to run test of normality to test if this is normally distributed, then followed by correlation among all variables and multiple regression.

Answer (score 3):

@Shirley, using the mean scores for each of the 8 questionnaires, even though they have different response anchors (i.e., 0-4 or 1-7 or 1-4), is definitely acceptable in multiple regression. In fact, it is very rare that you'll end up having measures/questionnaires that use the same set of response anchors.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! As I read from some stats articles, some researchers center or standardize the data. So I'm just confused..

Comment: On top of the 8 predictors variables, I'm also measuring gender difference on the online gaming addiction (my criterion variable). So obviously gender has 2 levels (Males and Females). Since it is nominal data, I'm thinking to use independent t test to test out the gender difference on the criterion variable. Wondering for this particular test, do I still use the mean or centered mean?

Comment: One last question...Just to confirm, it is fine to use the mean even the response anchors involves 0, correct?

Comment: Hi Shirley, I think each of these questions could be separated as they touch on different regression related methodological issues. But just to give you an idea:

Comment: Centering data is useful if you plan on running a moderation or mediated moderation analysis. For simple multiple regression there is really no need to standardize and center your data (as far as my knowledge of regression, but you may want to check with others).

Comment: You don't necessarily have to run t-tests (although it is an option) just because your outcome variable is gender. Technically, you could run a regression analysis with a dichotomous outcome variable, its just that the interpretation doesn't sound to great (i.e., as stress increases so does male(ness)?, etc.) but the analysis will tell you if there are significant relationships between gender and your other variables.

Comment: Regarding your question if it is fine to use means even if one of the anchors involves 0 I would definitely look at how other researchers have used the scales and computed the means, etc. This is very important and should be mentioned in your methods section.

Comment: CORRECTION: Centering data is useful for testing interactions, quadratic effects, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation! Indeed it helps! Thanks again!